# Code skips IF statement and goes straight to ELSE statement

Tags: python

//IF statment is completely skipped, but when i remove the ELSE statement, the IF statement works?

```
if fname != '' and lname != '' and user != '' and rank != '' and password != 
'' and  firenum != '' and phonenum != '' and phoneconfirm != '' and admin != 
'':
    if phonenum == phoneconfirm and len(phonenum) == int(10):
        get = AllPersonnel.query.filter_by(agencyid=current_user.agencyid).all()
        for i in get:
            if phonenum == i.phonenum:
                all = []
                all.append({'error' : 'ERROR: Phone number already exists in database'})
                return jsonify(all)
            else:
                pers = AllPersonnel(name.upper(), rank.upper(), firenum, phonenum, username, password, admin.upper(), agencyid, agencyname.upper(), availability, avtimestamp, enat, enattimestamp, taskavailbility, avtimetsamptask, plusdate)
                db.session.add(pers)
                db.session.commit()
                all = []
                all.append({'success' : 'SUCCESS: FireFighter added to database!'})
                return jsonify(all)
```

This is my other code that works for my other program.

```
        phoneemp = EmsaEmp.query.all()
        for num in phoneemp:
            if phonenum == num.phonenum:
                allexist = ('ERROR: Phone Number Already Exists In Database. Please Use The Help Desk or Contact a Supervisor. Thanks')
                return render_template('register.html', allexist=allexist)
            else:
                print('Success')
                ans = ''
                name = (fname + ' ' + lname)
                emp = EmsaEmp(name.upper(), title.upper(), phonenum, ans)
                db.session.add(emp)
                db.session.commit()
```

This is what i ended up doing and it works now.

```
if phonenum == phoneconfirm and len(phonenum) == int(10):
        get = AllPersonnel.query.filter_by(agencyid=current_user.agencyid).all()
        for i in get:
            if phonenum == i.phonenum:
                all = []
                all.append({'error' : 'ERROR: Phone number already exists in database'})
                return jsonify(all)
        for u in get:
            if phonenum != i.phonenum:
                pers = AllPersonnel(name.upper(), rank.upper(), firenum, phonenum, username, password, admin.upper(), agencyid, agencyname.upper(), availability, avtimestamp, enat, enattimestamp, taskavailbility, avtimetsamptask, plusdate)
                db.session.add(pers)
                db.session.commit()
                all = []
                all.append({'success' : 'SUCCESS: FireFighter added to database!'})
                return jsonify(all)
```

Comment: Why do you think the condition should be true?

Comment: What you mean to say is, with the code as it is there, it executes the contents of the else block (i.e. it appends a 'success'), and when you remove the else part, it executes the contents of the if block (i.e. it appends a 'error')?

Comment: If they input a phonenumber that already exists, it runs the IF statement. if phonenumber doesnt exist, then it runs  the ELSE statement. Same code works for my other program, but for some reason this doesnt.

Comment: Yes francisco, thats correct

Comment: @TreyThomas Just check the answer below

Comment: I suppose this is just because when you remove the else clause, the for loop is continuing with the next elements of your loop. And for one of them, the condition of th if clause is true...

Comment: Ok, so the problem is, it's not checking if the phonenumber exists in get, but rather checking one by one all phone numbers looking for a match. What ends up happening is, it only checks the first.

Comment: `for u in get:
            if phonenum != i.phonenum:` hohoho. if that works, you're really in trouble

Comment: haha i could have told you that. Whats the issue then?

Comment: have you tried not shadowing `all`? even if it's not the problem don't do it. anyway, without a testable code we can't help you

Comment: what do you mean by shadowing all?

Comment: don't give to your variables the name of a built-in type/function. `all` is a built-in function that you're using in your query

Answer (score 5):

You're in a loop.

So, on the first element, you would get the `else`, then `return` and never get to do the subsequent elements.

If you remove the else, you'll give your algo a chance to execute subsequent `if` statements.

I'd say your algo doesn't do what you wanted to do ;-).

Moreover, replace your huge `if` with

```
if all((fname, lname, user, rank, password, firenum, phonenum, phoneconfirm, admin)):
```

More info here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#all

And no need to do `len(phonenum) == int(10)`. Just `len(phonenum) == 10` is enough (Python is *at least* as simple as other languages, when not simpler)

Another issue:

```
            all = []
            all.append({'error' : 'ERROR: Phone number already exists in database'})
            return jsonify(all)
```

This can be rewritten into:

```
            return jsonify([{'error' : 'ERROR: Phone number already exists in database'}])
```

So that you don't create a temporary variable anymore (it's not the only problem about these 3 lines but I'll stop there).

## Big edit:

Please try the following piece of code:

```
import collections

PersonnelData = collections.namedtuple('PersonnelData', [
  'fname', 'lname', 'user', 'rank', 'password', 
  'firenum', 'phonenum', 'phoneconfirm', 'admin',
])

@app.route('/addpersonnellist', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addpersonnellist():
    data = PersonnelData(
        fname=request.args.get('fname'),
        lname=request.args.get('lname'),
        username=request.args.get('user'),
        rank=request.args.get('rank'),
        password=request.args.get('password'),
        firenum=request.args.get('firenumone'),
        phonenum=request.args.get('phonenum'),
        phoneconfirm=request.args.get('phonenumconfirm'),
        admin=request.args.get('admin'),
    )
    name = '{data.fname} {data.lname}'.format(data=data)
    if all(data):
        if phonenum == phoneconfirm and len(phonenum) == 10:
            personnel_phonenum = AllPersonnel.objects.values_list('phonenum', flat=True)
            if data.phonenum in personnel_phonenum:
                response = 'ERROR: Phone number already exists in database'
            else:
                pers = AllPersonnel(
                    name.upper(), data.rank.upper(), data.firenum, data.phonenum,
                    data.username, data.password, data.admin.upper(),
                    current_user.agencyid, current_user.agencyname.upper(),
                    '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
                )
                db.session.add(pers)
                db.session.commit()  # Can you do a commit when you're not in a transaction???
                response = 'SUCCESS: FireFighter added to database!'
        else:
            response = 'ERROR: Phone numbers do not match and/or format is invalid.'
    else:
        response = 'ERROR: Not all fields filled out correctly!'
    return jsonify({'response' : response})
```

As you'll notice, there's no for-loop. Try to use the actual API. Spend time to read the doc. It's not time lost.

Check this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Another alternative to the single `return` way, would be to use guard clauses: https://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html

```
import collections

PersonnelData = collections.namedtuple('PersonnelData', [
  'fname', 'lname', 'user', 'rank', 'password', 
  'firenum', 'phonenum', 'phoneconfirm', 'admin',
])

@app.route('/addpersonnellist', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def addpersonnellist():
    data = PersonnelData(
        fname=request.args.get('fname'),
        lname=request.args.get('lname'),
        username=request.args.get('user'),
        rank=request.args.get('rank'),
        password=request.args.get('password'),
        firenum=request.args.get('firenumone'),
        phonenum=request.args.get('phonenum'),
        phoneconfirm=request.args.get('phonenumconfirm'),
        admin=request.args.get('admin'),
    )

    if not all(data):
        return jsonify({'response' : 'ERROR: Not all fields filled out correctly!'})

    if not phonenum == phoneconfirm or len(phonenum) != 10:
        return jsonify({'response' : 'ERROR: Phone numbers do not match and/or format is invalid.'})

    personnel_phonenum = AllPersonnel.objects.values_list('phonenum', flat=True)

    if data.phonenum in personnel_phonenum:
        return jsonify({'response' : 'ERROR: Phone number already exists in database'})

    pers = AllPersonnel(
        '{data.fname} {data.lname}'.format(data=data).upper(),
        data.rank.upper(), data.firenum, data.phonenum,
        data.username, data.password, data.admin.upper(),
        current_user.agencyid, current_user.agencyname.upper(),
        '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
    )
    db.session.add(pers)
    db.session.commit()  # Can you do a commit when you're not in a transaction???

    return jsonify({'response' : 'SUCCESS: FireFighter added to database!'})
```

Comment: But my other program that runs this exact same code works perfectly.

Comment: Either it's not the same algo. Or it's not on the same dataset (the order of the phone numbers come differently). If the one you want comes first in your other program, then it'll look as if your algo is correct. But it's still not. Implement proper unit tests and you'll understand the mistake (that I'm pointing out) ;-)

Comment: Perhaps it just didn't have any repeated phone numbers, or the repeated one was the first on the list. In any case, both are wrong and you should, as @Samuel GIFFARD said, add some tests.

Comment: Moreover, replace your huge `if` with `if all((fname, lname, user, rank, password, firenum, phonenum, phoneconfirm, admin)):`. More info here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#all

Comment: @TreyThomas As I've told you, it's not the same algo for your other program. There's no `return` statement in your `else` block. ;-) This highlights another issue: DRY https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself

Comment: sorry, i didnt put the  rest of the else statement. there is actually a return. The only difference the two codes is that the top one i return a jsonify, the bottom code i return a render_template. dont know if that has anything to do with it

Comment: @TreyThomas Your new code is still wrong. You declare a temporary `u` and then use `i`. Again... it's not because it works with one test case that it will work with all. Try to have only one single `return` statement, at the very end of the function. It might help you write better code.

Comment: The problem is is that if i use only one return  statement, then i cant  pass in an error and a success. Should i use just one variable/argument to be passed through to my jquery?

Comment: http://dpaste.com/2KE9MK1   I did what you said Samuel, yet now imm not returning anything to my jquery

Comment: @TreyThomas Check my Edit.